# How do I implement a model that finds a correlation (not similarity) between query and target sentence?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, attention-model, sentence-similarity

When building an NLP model (I'm going to use an attention-based one), how can we implement one for finding the *correlation*, not *similarity*, between the query and target sentences?
For instance, the two sentences "I am an environmentalist." and "We should raise the gas price, ban combustion-engine vehicles, and promote better public transit." are somehow *similar* and *positively correlated*.  However, if the first sentence becomes "I am **not** an environmentalist.", the two sentences are still *similar* but now *negatively correlated*.

```py
import json
import azure.functions as func
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util

query = ["I am an environmentalist.",
         "I am not an environmentalist.",
         "I am a tech-savvy person."]
target = ["We should raise the gas price, ban combustion-engine vehicles, and promote better public transit."]

embedder = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')
query_embedding = embedder.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=True)
target_embedding = embedder.encode(target, convert_to_tensor=True)
searched = util.semantic_search(query_embedding, target_embedding)

print(searched)

# [
#     [{'corpus_id': 0, 'score': 0.30188844}],
#     [{'corpus_id': 0, 'score': 0.22667089}],
#     [{'corpus_id': 0, 'score': 0.05061193}]
# ]
```

Are there any useful resources or information about this difference and/or finding the *correlation* by a model? I'm still new to the field of NLP (I have used the sentence transformer for some of my projects) so maybe I simply didn't do a good search on the web.

Comment: There is no real scientific grounding for what you call "similarity" and "correlation". You are simply looking for a **semantic** similarity, but this is still a similarity. As long as said meaning can be extracted by a network the attention mechanism can pick up on it. Remember that transformers **learn** their similari space. This is not merely word-by-word comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have been looking around and found that it's somehow similar to aspect-based sentiment analysis (e.g., PyABSA: https://github.com/yangheng95/PyABSA) but am not sure what I need to do is "sentiment" or not.